# How macro definitions affect performance?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, macros

I am working on a project to rotate a two dimensional array. When I use the macro to replace some codes, the results are surprising in that everything is exactly the same. The time it takes to finish the task can be significantly different. I have always thought the macro to be just a placeholder, but how could this happen?

```
struct pixel
{
    unsigned short red;
    unsigned short green;
    unsigned short blue;
} ;

//n is the # of elements in the two dimensional array
void rotate1(int n, pixel *src, pixel *dst)
{
    int row, col, max = n - 1;
    for (row = 0; row < n; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < n; col++)
            *(dst+ (((max - row)*n)+col)) = *(src+ (row*n + col));
}

void rotate11(int n, pixel *src, pixel *dst)
{
#define TARGET  *(dst + (((max - row)*n)+col))
#define SOURCE  *(src + (row*n + col))

    int row, col, max = n - 1;
    for (row = 0; row < n; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            TARGET = SOURCE;
        }

}
```

The results are:

```
Time= 2.25 n= 512  Method= rotate1 
Time= 2.18 n= 512  Method= rotate11 

Time= 8.05 n= 1024  Method= rotate1 
Time= 8.08 n= 1024  Method= rotate11 

Time= 25.18 n= 2048  Method= rotate1 
Time= 25.24 n= 2048  Method= rotate11 

Time= 104.38 n= 4096  Method= rotate1 
Time= 104.21 n= 4096  Method= rotate11

Time= 1272.41 n= 8192  Method= rotate1 
Time= 423.00 n= 8192  Method= rotate11
```

When n is small the two have similar performance, but as n gets larger and larger the `rotate11` takes less and less time.

Comment: I question the statistical validity of your timing collection procedure. Looking at the few samples you've provided, each time you double n, you quadruple the time taken… except for one outlier (which I would strongly suggest is due to external circumstances unrelated to your code, given the data you've provided).

Comment: Macro expansion takes place even before compiling your code, so there should be no relation between them and your code's performance.

Comment: Do you understand what a preprocessor directive is? ;) If you did you would know that macros have nothing to do with the runtime of your code.

Comment: Aside from the question, why not use memcpy for the entire matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macros are expanded by the C preprocessor before the code is seen by the compiler.

You can create the preprocessor output via the -E option in gcc.

For example:

gcc -E foo.c -o foo.i     /* to create the preprocessor text file output */

vs

gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o     /* to create the object file output */

If open foo.i in your editor of choice, you will see the MACROs expanded as source code.

I don't really see how MACROS are impacting your performance.

Answer (score 7):

The two examples are identical as far as your compiler is concerned. Are you running the two examples in the same run? What's likely happening is the first function ran (irrespective whether you used macros or not) is filling the caches and the second one is running much faster because of that.

What if you change the order in which the functions are called, or limit to one function run per execution? You should see almost identical performance.

Comment: It's a good point, but then - how come the results are identical for smaller n values? you'd expect the same ratio between the cold and warm iterations.

Comment: A lot of things could have happened. I think the likeliest being that for smaller values of `n` the entire data fit inside the cache working set and was likely preemptively cached by the architecture. Modern processors are exceptionally good at predicting what to cache.

Comment: Hmm, the processor won't preemptively fill 4M of array into the cache and throw away everything else, it would just prefetch ahead of your stream (but then both calls should enjoy it). Anyway, if it's too big to fit some cache level, then you also won't benefit from the second function call having it there.

Comment: The preprocessor has nothing to do with this. For all values of `n`, they're operating on the same block of memory, although in the same order. They're just using less of it. What I was saying is the part that the code touches could have been all in L2 or L1 cache by then.

Comment: I didn't say preprocessor, I was replying about the "Modern processors..." comment. And about the caching - you already got my +1 :), I'm just saying that if that was the cause, then for all n values you'd get the same effect, and only once you can't fit in the largest cache the effect would be gone. Here we see the other way around. I think the reason is less prosaic, just a glitch in measurement - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect some effect of memory caching. To be sure you may try to make 4 calls, run1, run11, run 1, run11, your data have memory access patterns that may lead to a high cost of data loading the first time...

Answer (score 1):

There's a steady growth pattern here - as @mah pointed out - everytime you grow `n` by 2x, you grow the runtime by 4x, which makes sense since your arrays are n^2.

According to this, your last call (n=8192) should be ~400 long, as the second call indeed shows. I'm willing to bet that there was simply some unexpected event during the first call (context switch or some other interruption) causing it to get stalled - you should run a few iterations and see if it reproduces